# Group_Concat insert data into separate cells

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel, group-concat

I am struggling in here a bit, I have a `group_concat` and I want each value to be separated into a different cell in order for a total cell to get the sum of these concatenated values.

```
$this->db->select("date, reference_no, biller, customer, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(" . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".product_name) SEPARATOR '\n') as iname, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(round( " . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".quantity)) SEPARATOR '\n') as cqty, GROUP_CONCAT(TRUNCATE(CONCAT(" . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".net_unit_price),2) SEPARATOR '\n') as unitbeforetax,GROUP_CONCAT(ROUND( CONCAT(" . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".net_unit_price *  " . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".quantity ),2) SEPARATOR '\n') as beforetax,GROUP_CONCAT(round(CONCAT(" . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".item_tax),2 ) SEPARATOR '\n') as producttax,GROUP_CONCAT(round(CONCAT(" . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".unit_price *  " . $this->db->dbprefix('sale_items') . ".quantity),2) SEPARATOR '\n') as unitp, grand_total, paid, payment_status", FALSE)
```

I am calling the concat into phpexcel so the syntax is:

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F' . $row, $data_row->unitbeforetax);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G' . $row, $data_row->beforetax);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H' . $row, $data_row->producttax);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I' . $row, $data_row->unitp);
```

Now this will return the result in new line but Excel and phpexcel will not calculate the sum in this format :

```
1
1
```

What I need is for each value to be separated into new cell under the main cell or any separator that excel will accept when calculating values...

Thanks in advance